# Loading EXR from GLB buffer doesn't work (loading from path does)

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I am trying to load a GLB model with a custom embedded EXR file, I use the following code to try and load it from the buffer. However this does not work...

When I try to load the EXR directly with the `EXRLoader().load(url)` function that does work, leading me to believe the EXR is not corrupt... Are there other step requirements when parsing an EXR file to get lighting into the scene?

```js
var parser = gltf.parser;
var bufferPromises = parser.getDependency("bufferView", parser.json.images[2].bufferView);

bufferPromises.then(function (buffer) {
    var texData = that.assetLoader.parseEXR(buffer);
    var texture = new THREE.DataTexture()

    texture.image = texData.image;
    texture.image.width = texData.width;
    texture.image.height = texData.height;
    texture.image.data = texData.data;
             
    texture.format = texData.format;
    texture.type = texData.type;
    texture.colorSpace = THREE.LinearSRGBColorSpace;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.generateMipmaps = false;
    texture.flipY = false;

    var envMap = that.pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture)
    that.exr = envMap.texture;
    that.scene.environment = envMap;
    that.scene.background = envMap.texture;
});
```